# Android: Is it possible to dynamically change the border color of a EditText?

Tags: android, border, android-edittext

I would like to change the Orange border around a `EditText`. Like when the input is valid, I want it to become green.

[alt text http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/images/hello-relativelayout.png](http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/views/images/hello-relativelayout.png)

However I do not seem to find a method to do this. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible to change the orange border easily because it's actually a 9-patch - that is, the entire border + white background is a 9-patch that Android uses by default.  It uses the `android:background` attribute to set it, too.

It would be possible to acquire a copy of the 9-patch (it will be in your SDK), edit the color to make it green, then in code configure it so that your 9-patch is set as the background of the EditText when the input is valid.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the background really is a `StateListDrawable`, of which the orange-border nine-patch PNG is just one of the images for one of the states.